# Edit <title> data using a <span> division on the page

Tags: jquery, title, html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="js.js"></script>
        <script>
            var name = $("#postheading").text();
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("title").text(name)    
            }); 
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span id="postheading">THE PAGE TITLE INFO or POST HEADING</span>
    </body>
</html>
```

I hope my question is clear from the code above. But unfortunately it isn't working. I have many pages and want to have the `<title>` info from heading of the post (for my blog), i.e. my span element with `id="postheading"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this,

```
    $(document).ready(function(){           
        $("title").text($("#postheading").text());  
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to retrieve the `#postheading` value within the `document.ready` block. Secondly, you can use the native `document.title` to set the page title. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var name = $("#postheading").text();
    document.title = name;
});
```

Comment: It isn't working. I am getting the file name instead of the text inside <title> (I added something inside <title> to check the code).